# Android enableTransitionType just work once

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

I'm using `enableTransitionType` to animate the `layoutParmas` from `0` to `screen width` when pressing a button. But it only works for the very first time.

What I did is in the linearlayout add 
`android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

Then,

```
layout.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)

val layoutParams = layout.layoutParams
layoutParams.width = width
layout.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Only the first time press the button, it works. I also tried add another button press it then
`layout.layoutTransition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)`

Any idea, thanks!